Generics in Interface makes all list generic in JAVA
When using generics in a interface method, all other methods of the interface involving list of concrete classes are not being resolved properly.
interface Fruit<T extends Fruit>
{
    public List<String> getColors();
    public List<T> getChildren();
}
    
class FruitUtil
{
    public static void readFruit(Fruit fruit)
    {
        // shows error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String
        for(String color : fruit.getColors()) { }

        // shows error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Fruit
        for(Fruit thisFruit : fruit.getChildren()) { }
    }
}

Here, though I've used generics to represent the list of children of Fruit, I have a concrete String list to represent fruit's colors.
But, when using getColors() of Fruit, it is returning List instead of List<String>, despite it having the exact return type.
Am I missing anything here?

You are using fruit as a raw type. Add the generic type - readFruit(Fruit<SomeTypeExtendingFruit> fruit)

Or make FruitUtil generic, too (or rather, its methods, as it's static): public static <T> void readFruit(Fruit<T> fruit) {...} so you can address it as T in there, too.

Turn on all compiler warnings.  They would have told you what the problem was.

You are using Fruit as a raw type, and therefore the return type of any of its methods is treated as the erasure of that type.
So in the following line:
    for(String color : fruit.getColors())

The object fruit is of a raw type and therefore getColors() returns the erasure, List, equivalent to List<Object>. This is specified by the Java Language Specification section on raw types:

The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the erasure of its type in the generic class or interface C.

Note that raw types exist to facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code written prior to Java 1.5, i.e. more than 20 years ago. They should be avoided. The JLS warns you not to use them:

The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

You have raw types in various places in your code. One way to fix them is as follows:
interface Fruit<T extends Fruit<T>>
...
    public static void readFruit(Fruit<?> fruit)
...
        for(Fruit<?> thisFruit : fruit.getChildren())


k314159 answers correctly explains the underlying issue but I want to add an alternative solution:
interface Fruit<T extends Fruit<T>>
{
    public List<String> getColors();
    public List<T> getChildren();
}

class FruitUtil
{
    public static <T extends Fruit<T>> void readFruit(Fruit<T> fruit)
    {
        // shows error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String
        for(String color : fruit.getColors()) { }

        // shows error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Fruit
        for(Fruit thisFruit : fruit.getChildren()) { }
    }
}


Ensure that T extends Fruit<T>, so it refers to a subtype of Fruit consistently.
Declare <T extends Fruit<T>> in readFruit, making it a generic method, to correctly handle the generic type, which allows you to iterate over fruit.getChildren() as a type compatible with the interface formal type parameter instead of the raw type Fruit.

Compared to k314159 proposed solution using unbounded wildcards:

Using <?> makes the method less type-safe. For instance, you lose the ability to treat the child fruits (thisFruit) as their specific types in other parts of the code. The wildcard type (<?>) means you can’t call methods that rely on the specific type T. The best you can do is treat the children as generic Fruit<?>, limiting what you can do with them.

If you have specific subtypes of Fruit, you won't be able to leverage those subtypes when working with the children in getChildren(). They all will be treated generically as Fruit<?>.



Get rid of the raw types:
interface Fruit<T extends Fruit<T>>
{
    List<String> getColors();
    List<T> getChildren();
}

class FruitUtil
{
    public static void readFruit(Fruit<?> fruit)
    {
        for(String color : fruit.getColors())
        {

        }
        for(Fruit<?> thisFruit : fruit.getChildren())
        {

        }
    }
}

